# Peer review papers

Tags: discussion

I'm new to this forum and wanted to ask if there is forum where I can post my term paper for peer review/critique sort of thing. This particular topic happens to be on quantum computing.

Comment: you can post it to your blog, or if you think it is good enough to interest researchers then the [ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/) with your prof's endorsement.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is appropriate. cstheory is a Q&A site. Please refer to the [FAQ](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/about) pages for more information about the scope of the site.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a forum and won't help you much with your paper.

Posting your paper (in plain text) to the [comp.theory Usenet group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/comp.theory) hopefully would attract some attention without annoying anyone.

Comment: Traffic on comp.theory is very low and consists almost entirely cranks and spam.  I doubt many (any?) serious researchers still read it.